# How can I create a loop that terminates at any desired year (C++)?

Tags: c++, loops

I was faced with creating a program that can tell a user how much interest will be added to a product after any arbitrary number of years. I had to use a loop to estimate the new price, among other things.

The problem I ran into was in the creation of the loop. I didn't know how to make it stop at any specific year that a user chose. What I did is made a for loop that outputted the loop for the next 99 years. This was my loop:
for (time>0; time<=99; time++) where time was the number of years from today.

This is obviously not ideal. I wrote this in frustration from not knowing how to create a loop that can end wherever the user wants. How can I create a loop that terminates at any desired year?

Comment: "specified number of years" you're not supposed to stop on a specific year (e.g. "in the year 2525"), you're supposed to stop after a certain number of years (e.g. "in 525 years from now")

Comment: Take the [tour] and see [ask]. Also read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: for(int i=2020; i<=EndYear; ++i) price *= 1.056;

Comment: This looks like a "homework" question.  This is really not the forum for answering this style of question.  You should probably start with a basic c++ book to get yourself started with variables, loops, and conditionals.  Or show us code that you have written and we can make suggestions.

Comment: *"What I did is made a for loop that outputted the loop for the next 99 years."* -- this is your starting point. Your question should include the loop that you made. **However** you might be better served by [explaining to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) (or a friend, or even the mirror) why your loop works for `99` but cannot be modified to work for user input..

Comment: Can you show the program you've already written, and explain how exactly your program doesn't work or doesn't produce the expected results? You have to show your work first; it must meet all requirements for a [mre]; and it must be a good-faith real attempt to implement your program and not a few token lines of code, before asking for help on stackoverflow.com. We don't write entire programs for other people, here. For more information, see [ask] questions, take the [tour], and read the [help].

Answer (score 0):

```
for (time>0; time<=99; time++)
```

This will stop at a predefined number, i.e. `99`. To make it stop at a number given by user you need to:

1. Get the number from the user and save it in a variable
2. Replace `99` with the variable in your loop